# Delayed Job - Rails 3 - Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Has anyone gotten Delayed Job working on Heroku Beta for Rails 3?

We switched over to rails 3 and now I can no longer activate delayed job with "rake jobs:work"

Answer (score 1):

do you have active workers?  It sounds like you have a job queue but no workers to process.  Try this:

```
$ heroku workers 1
```

for more information: [Running DJ workers on Heroku](http://docs.heroku.com/delayed-job)